# Why can't stringify convert back to json after parse

Tags: scala, scala.js, upickle

Say I define the following case classes:

```
case class A(i: Int)
case class B(str: String)
case class T(a: A, b: B)
```

I then convert to json, parse back and try to convert again as follows:

```
val json = write(T(A(1), B("One")))
val parsed = JSON.parse(json).asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[js.Any]].toMap
println("Json: " + json)
parsed.foreach { case (k, v) =>
    println(s"$k: ${v.toString}")
    println("Stringify: " + JSON.stringify(v, js.Array[js.Any]()))
}
```

I get the following output:

> Json: {"a":{"i":1},"b":{"str":"One"}}
>
> a: [object Object]
>
> Stringify: {}
>
> b: [object Object]
>
> Stringify: {}

Why does neither toString nor stringify correctly convert the objects back to json?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is passing an empty array for the replacer parameter for stringify. This should be null